# Can't request GET in some API on ALEXA

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having trouble on requesting some API, when I write on my backend code (lambda) for Alexa

```
const request = require('sync-request');

var url = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/projecoes/populacao';


var response = request('GET', url);
```

it works perfectly fine for others APIs, or on my local IDE.

Comment: so... why does it fail? Have you attempted to add any form of error handling to it? Have you inspected the response?

Comment: I tried to try and catch but didn't show me any error on aws, but on alexa simulator tell me: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

Comment: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" generally means something in your skill is throwing. Have you checked the CloudWatch logs (assuming you've deployed a lambda).

In your catch, are you logging the error?

You might also want to consider adding an error handler - https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Processing-Request.html?highlight=adderrorhandler#error-handlers

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely suggest you using async request when using an external API. I suggest you take a look at [this](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a9ef18b2-ef68-44d4-86eb-dbdb293853bb/alexa-skill-recipe-making-http-requests-to-get-data-from-an-external-api) or [this](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/4a46da08-d1b8-4d8e-9277-055307a9bf4a/alexa-skill-recipe-update-call-and-get-data-from-external-apisblog) or [this](https://github.com/germanviscuso/ASKVideoSeries/tree/master/07).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, my I suggest you to take a look at how it is done in this case https://github.com/frivas/hello-world-skill-tom/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js